# Input auto complete initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div when double clicked, I create an input and initialized it as an auto complete. when I double click the first time the auto complete doesn't work.

But It works when i focus out of the div, and double click on the same div again. The auto complete works when double click the second time on the same div.

How can I initialize the auto complete so that it would work the first time i double click on the div

```
HTML:
<td>
<div class = "Edit"/>
</td>


$('.Edit').on('dblclick', function (evt) {
    var $target = $(evt.target),
        $td = $target.parent(),
        $editdiv = $('<div></div>').appendTo($td),
        $input = $('<input/>').appendTo($editdiv);
    $input.autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 1,
        source: datasrc,
        select: selectedItem
    });
});
```

Note : For source I use Json data

Answer (score 0):

After creating your dynamic input

```
$( ".Edit" ).dblclick(function(evt) {
      var $target = $(evt.target),
       $td = $target.parent(),
       $editdiv = $('<div></div>').appendTo($td),
       $input = $('<input id="someInput"/>').appendTo($editdiv);
});
```

you can use [jQuery appear plugin](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear). which fires when an element scrolls into view or otherwise becomes visible to the user.

```
 $('#someInput').appear(function() {
     $('#someInput').autocomplete({
          source: someObject,
     });
 });
```

Comment: I would like delete the $editdiv when blurred from Original Div which is div with 'Edit' class. Hence I would not be able to use appear plugin

Comment: It's not clear to me. appear plugin will fire when any div is appeared that means when you create your dynamic input it will fire and initialize the autocomplete to that input. I thought you just want to add autocomplete to your dynamic input. Can you please tell elaborately what you expect. Or can you make a jsfiddle??